# why does this code sort an object based on the order of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

the `sortWeekFunction` could sort an object based on the order of an array.
but it's quite hard to understand why.
how exactly does this code work?

```js
const weeksArr = ['sunday', 'monday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'];

const weeksObj = {
  wednesday: 'wednesday',
  friday: 'friday',
  monday: 'monday',
  thursday: 'thursday',
  sunday: 'sunday',
};

const sortWeekFunction = (array, object) => {
  const newMapSortObj = new Map(Object.entries(object));
  const sortObj = Array.from(newMapSortObj)?.sort(
    (a, b) => array.indexOf(a[0]) - array.indexOf(b[0])
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(sortObj);
};

console.log(sortWeekFunction(weeksArr, weeksObj))
// {
//     sunday: 'sunday',
//     monday: 'monday',
//     wednesday: 'wednesday',
//     thursday: 'thursday',
//     friday: 'friday',
// }
```

Comment: The sort routine is defined here as a lambda `(a, b) => array.indexOf(a[0]) - array.indexOf(b[0])`. This basically says, sort by using the index of the item found within the provided array. The array is sunday, monday, ... So that is the sort order. Note that `sortWeekFunction` returns an object which generally isn't required to be "sorted" regardless, so the end result doesn't do much for you other than arrange the object's keys in a desired order (again, typically not important). If you want a sorted collection, a JavaScript Object/Map/Dictionary is not the appropriate data type.

Comment: There is a lot in this snippet that is completely unneccesary. The conversion to a Map and then to an array, the optional chaining operator (Array.from always returns an array), and finally the sorting of an object's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sort an object" doesn't quite make sense. What you are describing is sorting the **Object's keys**. Note that in the majority of use cases, the order of an object's keys does not matter. Object's (also Maps/Dictionaries) are not an appropriate data structure for storing sorted collections. Use an array/list for storing such collections, or just do something like `Array.from(Object.keys(obj)).sort()` if you ever want to sort the keys of an object `obj`.

To answer you question regarding why the code works. We need to first take a closer look at the `sortWeekFunction` function.

```js
const sortWeekFunction = (array, object) => {
  const newMapSortObj = new Map(Object.entries(object));
  const sortObj = Array.from(newMapSortObj)?.sort(
    (a, b) => array.indexOf(a[0]) - array.indexOf(b[0])
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(sortObj);
};
```

To start with, a `Map` is created from the object's entries. A map is a comparable data structure to a JavaScript `Object`, though it has a few different properties. The `Map` is used as part of array creation here:

```
Array.from(newMapSortObj)
```

The above will produce the following:

```
[
  [ 'wednesday', 'wednesday' ],
  [ 'friday', 'friday' ],
  [ 'monday', 'monday' ],
  [ 'thursday', 'thursday' ],
  [ 'sunday', 'sunday' ]
]
```

Note that the above is an "array of arrays."

Then you use the array's `.sort()` method with a custom sort routine, defined as a lambda here:

```
sort(
    (a, b) => array.indexOf(a[0]) - array.indexOf(b[0])
  );
```

The above essentially iterates through pairs of elements within the array and evaluates `array.indexOf(a[0]) - array.indexOf(b[0])`. If `a[0]` is `wednesday` and `b[0]` is `sunday`, for example, then the index of `sunday` would be `0` based on your provided sortArray and the index of `wednesday` would be `2`.

The result of this operation would be `2`. That indicates that the element containing `sunday` *should come before* the element containing `wednesday`. The same operation occurs for the other pairs of elements and the operation results indicate the appropriate ordering. *It's worth researching [how .sort() works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a `compareFn` for a deeper understanding of how this is actually working.*

Finally, you create an object from the entries in your sorted array with `Object.fromEntries(sortObj)` and return it.

The result is an object with sorted keys.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, a solid aha moment, thanks a lot!

Comment: @BenTsai I also strongly recommend that you look into the link I provided regarding "how .sort() works" in JavaScript. It should result in even more "aha!" moments.